# Switching between two typedef structs, depending on boolean

Tags: c++, struct, typedef

I have a class with different functions. This class uses two typedef structs.

```
typedef struct {
   struct head;
   struct data1;
} data_struct_1;

typedef struct {
   struct head;
   struct data2;
} data_struct_2;
```

If a bool is true the data_struct_2 should be used, otherwise data_struct_1. The boolean is passed, when the object is created and stored as a membervariable in the constructor.

There are now different functions and declarations like

```
int calc_mean(data_struct_1 ds, int a){ ... }
```

or

```
data_struct_1 ds;
ds.data1 = 5;
```

Is there an elegant way, which allows me to switch between those two structs without implementing dozens of if-cases and duplicate all the relevant functions with the corresponding struct in the header?
First I was thinking about inheritance and overwritting relevant functions if bool is true.. but the header in the functions differs, so this wouldnt work
Maybe there is something like a placeholder or template, but i'm pretty new to c++

Comment: If there are different fields in the two structs, then they too should be part of the derived and not of the base. In general, if two classes are very similar, they should be either (1) children of the same base class or (2) instantiations of the same class template (or maybe both). It is really hard to tell what exactly you should do without knowing a whole lot more about your specific use case.

Comment: Is this definitely C++, like the tag, or C as the construction `typedef struct { ... } Foo;` suggests? (It does also work in C++ but you'd typically just write `struct Foo { ... };`)

Comment: Did any of the answers help? If so, please upvote those that did and accept the answer that helped the most. If not, please edit your question to clarify what you're after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

1. If the types are conceptually the same type of thing (i.e. they have the same interface and could be substituted for one another), you can:

   1. Create an abstract base type and use polymorphism to change which concrete type is instantiated
   2. Change all places that use these types into templates, change which template(s) are instantiated at runtime, and then rely on compile-time "duck-typing" to do the rest
2. If the types are conceptually different (i.e. they should *not* have the same interface), you can use a union type (`union`, [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant)).

Answer (score 2):

If boolean is compile-time value, [`std::conditional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional) might be used:

```
template <boolean B>
using my_type = std::conditional_t<B, data_struct_1, data_struct_2>;
```

but it seems the boolean is runtime value, so I would use [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) and [`std::visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit):

```
class C
{
    using Data = std::variant<data_struct_1, data_struct_2>;
    Data m_data;
public:
    C(bool b) : m_data{b ? Data{data_struct_1{}} : Data{data_struct_2{}}} {}


    auto mean() const {
        return std::visit([](const auto& data){ return calc_mean(data, 42); }, m_data);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to use [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant):

```
typedef std::variant<data_struct_1, data_struct_2> data_struct_1_or_2;

void foo(data_struct_1_or_2 ds) {
    if (auto ds1 = std::get_if<data_struct_1>(&ds)) {
        // use ds1, which is type data_struct_1*
    } else if (auto ds2 = std::get_if<data_struct_2>(&ds)) {
        // use d2, which is type data_struct_2*
    } else {
        throw std::logic_error("Unexpected value in variant");
    }
}

void bar(data_struct_1_or_2 ds) {
    foo(ds); // Don't need to use an if statement here
}
```

If you have a `data_struct_1` or `data_struct_2` and want to pass a reference to the object, rather than a copy, you could use pointers in the `std::variant` instead (although it'll get a bit confusing with `std::get_if` because you'll end up with a pointer to a pointer):

```
typedef std::variant<data_struct_1*, data_struct_2*> data_struct_1_or_2_ptr;
```

Comment: [`std::visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit) allows to get rid of "`if else`" chain and ensure each variant is handled. (`overloaded` from cppreference help page might help).

Comment: @Jarod42 Sure, but then you need to explode your `foo()` function out into multiple functions. If that function has local variables that are used in different branches, or you want to exercise early return, this can be quite a bit of a pain. It's worth everyone knowing about both techniques so they can make an informed judgement about which to use, given the trade-offs.

Comment: As I stated, `overloaded` and lambda avoid extra functions. The big problem with `if` is when you want to add `data_struct_3` to the variant. You have to check mostly all the code manually, whereas`std::visit` won't compile for not handled case.

Comment: @Jarod42 Oops, you're right, I missed the reference to `overloaded`, that does allow the branches to be defined in place. It's still a more complex solution than a few `if` statements though. You can't use control structures like `return` or `break` in them in the way you'd expect, and the bracket soup just uses a bit more cognative load for the reader. The ability to detect missed cases at compile time is great but you have to trade it off against those negatives - in some code, cases are so rarely added or so obviously caught that this benefit isn't worth it.

Comment: @Jarod42 It's a classic mistake to choose what feels like the philosphically "right" solution in favour of something only slightly lacking but much simpler. It's very much like the drive that causes beginners to optimise functions that are rarely called, causing an increase in complexity for no noticable benefit, hence the classic adage against premature optimisation. Anyway, so long as both answers are present here, readers can make their own decision about the trade offs in their situation.

Comment: there are work-around for `return`/`break` usage, but, when we need it, it generally means that function is too big. The choice for me is straightforward, I saw so many code with broken if-chain (including derived manual dispatch). I don't see it as more complex. I really see `std::visit` as default way to use `std::variant` and `std::get_if` as exception.

Comment: For premature optimization, I think it is mostly due to the way we teach/learn programming... :-( and now the fact that people use competitive programming site to learn by him/herself...

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant).

A variant can hold a number of alternative types, like this:

```
std::variant<data_struct_1, data_struct_2> m;
```

The member `m` can contain either a `data_struct_1` or a `data_struct_2`. The `variant` will remember which, so there's no need for you to carry that `bool` around anymore.

The interesting question is now, how do you treat `m` in your functions? After all, it could be either a `data_struct_1` or a `data_struct_2` in there. Instead of using branches for distinguishing these cases, `variant` uses [`visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit): Whenever you encounter a point in the function that depends on the concrete type stored in `m`, you move that code into two overloaded functions: One function that handles the `data_struct_1` case and another that handles the `data_struct_2` case. The example on the [`visit` cppreference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit) shows some possibilities for doing that with varying degrees of syntactic overhead.

The good thing about this approach is that it forces you to always handle both cases properly. You can't just go ahead and write an implementation for one case and then forget about the other, having it blow up later at runtime. It also encourages a style where you clearly separate common parts of your code from type-specific parts, which often results in a cleaner design in the long term.

Answer (score 1):

A simple C solution would be a `union` with a `bool` tag:

```
  typedef struct {
    struct head;
    bool type_flag;
    union{
        struct data1 d1;
        struct data2 d2
    };
  } data_struct;
```

`std::variant` is an overkill for this case IMO. Inheritance and runtime polymorphism is a waste of runtime and memory.

Regards,
FM.